# Strange domain dependency with Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm using Mathematica 8 and strangely enough this code:

```
    Maximize[{x*(1-0.01 x),x>0},x,Integers]
```

produces the result `{8.19,{x->9}}`, which seems at odds with the actual answer of `x->25`.

Does anyone know if it is an intended behavior or my mistake?

Comment: Just for fun, try **Maximize[{x*(1 - 0.01 x), x > 0}, x]** :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Szabolcs stated, `Maximize` is calling `NMaximize`.

The problem is that the call is not being done with appropriate options for your case. Just compare for example:

```
NMaximize[{x*(1 - 0.01 x), x ∈ Integers}, x]
(*
x-> 19
*)
```

with

```
NMaximize[{x*(1 - 0.01 x), x ∈ Integers}, x, MaxIterations -> 300]
(*
x-> 50
*)
```

To understand better what is happening you may see the evaluation process:

```
f[x_] := x*(1 - .01 x);
{sol, pts} = Reap[
   NMaximize[{f[x], x ∈ Integers}, x, MaxIterations -> 300,  
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f[x]}]]];
{sol1, pts1} = Reap[
   NMaximize[{f[x], x ∈ Integers}, x,  
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f[x]}]]];

GraphicsGrid[{{
   Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 100}, Epilog -> Map[Point, Cases[First[pts] , x_]]],
   Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 100}, Epilog -> Map[Point, Cases[First[pts1], x_]]]}}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

As Szabolcs  commented below, the evaluation process is far from efficient.
Here you have the number of evaluations done for each integer x while the algorithm is trying to find the Max:

```
Histogram[(First@pts1)[[All, 1]], {-1, 20, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "# of evals"}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

You could run

```
Histogram[Select[Length /@ Split@(First[pts1][[All, 1]]), # > 1 &]]
```

To see that it evaluates the *same* x several times is a row!

Comment: Nice analysis!  It is weird though that the function is called so many times with the *same* argument (the same elements appear many times in `pts` and `pts1`).  If `f` is expensive to evaluate, this is really wasteful.

Comment: It is better to evaluate `NMaximize[{x*(1 - 0.01 x), x \[Element] Integers}, x, 
   MaxIterations -> #] & /@ (50 Range[6])`. It shows more details with messages generated.

Comment: @Szabolcs If that is the case, memoization could help

Comment: @R.M Thanks for the edit

Comment: @Szabolcs See edit

Comment: Thanks, @belisarius! Will be using your convergence graphs very often.

Answer (score 14):

You are using [inexact numbers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ExactAndApproximateResults.html) in the input (`0.01`).  The documentation says that in this case `Maximize` will call `NMaximize` and will try to solve the problem using numerical methods.  So your input is equivalent to

```
NMaximize[{x*(1 - 0.01 x), x > 0, x ∈ Integers}, x]
```

Here something goes wrong with the numerical method, and the returned answer is not correct.

Generally, when using functions that do symbolic operations, it is a good idea to only use exact numbers.  The following input will give you the correct result:

```
Maximize[{x*(1 - 1/100 x), x > 0}, x, Integers]

(* ==> {25, {x -> 50}} *)
```

Generally, the function [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rationalize.html) is useful in converting expressions with lots of inexact numbers into exact ones.  Try `Rationalize[0.01]`.

Related reading:

- [The Uncertainties of Numerical Mathematics](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheUncertaintiesOfNumericalMathematics.html)

Comment: Seems like the problem is not the numerical method, but the default number of iterations used by NMaximize[]. See my answer. It is easy to see what is happening by using EvaluationMonitor.

Answer (score 7):

Often `NMaximize` (which as others indicated is used behind the scenes) will work better if given some indication of a "useful" search space.

Realistic:

```
In[7]:= Maximize[{x*(1-0.01 x),100>x>0},x,Integers]
Out[7]= {25., {x -> 50}}
```

Too big:

```
In[8]:= Maximize[{x*(1-0.01 x),10000>x>0},x,Integers]
Out[8]= {4.75, {x -> 5}}
```

Comment: Do you know why `NMaximize` seems to evaluate the function *for the very same argument* many times, according to `EvaluationMonitor`?  This happens also if I pass a "black-box" function to `NMaximize` and record the arguments passed to it inside the function (so it's not a problem with `EvaluationMonitor`): `f[x_?NumericQ] := (Sow[x]; ...)`  This seems rather inefficient and it only happens when using `x \[Element] Integers`.

Comment: There are two aspects to this. One is the work done in repeatedly evaluating a function at the same point. NMaximize et al do not memo-ize function evaluations (unless the definition of the function does that itself). The disadvantage is, as you observe, that reevaluations take place. The advantage is it rarely runs out of memory. The second issue is that it uses derivative-free methods that involve doing comparisons between old and new points (this happens with simulated annealing, differential evolution, and Nelder-Mead). So of necessity there will be reevaluations at points already visited.

Comment: There you have a nice candidate for an option **Memoize -> {True , False, N}**